# Create basic JVZOO api with PHP

Tags: php, json

I am new to JVZOO API. I want to create a small api for the features below:

USER
1. User enter purchase ID
2. It checks if valid transaction
3. If correct, they see link to download coupon

ADMIN
1. Paste list of coupon codes
2. Shows datatable of codes that was used (name of person)
3. Codes can't be used again (admin can delete a code anytime)

Help please. 
Thanks.

Comment: Hi ! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that “Help please” is nothing but a proper question: you should give code samples showing what you have tried so far, and explaining what your issue is

Comment: help with what, specifically? What have you done about researching and then trying to code your requirement so far? What are you stuck with, exactly? If you don't even know where to start then it's too early to ask a question here - we deal in code and bug fixes, you need to do some research, read documentation and examples about the tool you're using. Don't assume that anyone knows what on earth JVZOO is either. There's no tag or community for it here, so perhaps linking us to an explanation would help as well.

Comment: link to the API: https://api.jvzoo.com/docs/versions/v2.0.html#jvzoo-api-v2.0